# how to request the JSON file from this/an URL and make it into html in the page?

Tags: javascript, json, youtube

this might be a bit too specific, but i asked at a lot of other places, and they just tried to convince me that i cant run javascript on any website any time.

i need to request the JSON file from this URL (for example):
https://www.youtube.com/watch_fragments_ajax?v=RF1d-vJ8tP8&tr=scroll&frags=comments

its a youtube JSON file  containing a comment section (if im right).
i tried requesting it on youtube itself on the corresponding video page, but when i view the Net panel in Firebug, it always says that my request was forbidden. the original request requests from the same URL, and it can even be resent successfully (right-click, resend in Firebug).

i would need to know how to successfully request the file, and then parse/turn it into html so i can embed it in the page. you can see the original request in Firebug's Net tab and XHR tab in it, when the comments load under a video.

even if nothing else, the request itself would be enough for me.
i would be grateful if someone helped.

Comment: there are some limitation about cross site request via Javascript, you might want consider do it on your server side.

Comment: but the request URL is on the youtube domain. and i would run the javascript on the youtube domain. could you just tell me how i should do the reqest?